# fixed positioned button in mobile website

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-website

I am building a mobile website and need a fixed positioned button (for quick link to scroll to top) that should move across while scrolling the screen. fixed position is not supported by mobile browsers. Can anyone suggest the way around for the same. I am using twitter bootstrap. I have observed fixed position header and footers for mobile in jquery mobile framework but could use it in twitter bootstrap page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `navbar-fixed-top` or `navbar-fixed-bottom` navbar on your site and that will function properly on mobile devices. Refer to the Optional Display variations section under navbars http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar.